# Mysql Query to display not matched records from both tables like old record and new record

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two two tables , one is temporary table and another one is main table.Before doing final process user click on refresh button . Then I am populating data into the temporary table and need to display to user if there is any difference between two tables like old value - new value. For this I tried below query but not able get the old value. I am getting as null

```
Temporay table

+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
| asn        |       ean |   belegnr |quantity|
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
|  700000845 | 4046228201122| 30059314 |2  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138879| 30059314 |3  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138875| 30059320 |25 |
+------+--------------+----------------+--+--+
```

Main Table

```
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
| asn        |       ean |   belegnr |quantity|
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+
|  700000845 | 4046228201122| 30059314 |5  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138879| 30059314 |3  |
|  700000845 | 4046228138888| 30059320 |25 |
+------+--------------+----------------+--+--+
```

From both tables I have change in ean field and in quantity field
For this I am using this query

```
SELECT
t2.id,t2.ean,t2.belegnr,t2.`quantity`,t1.`quantity`  FROM
temp_table  t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN details  t1 ON
t1.asn = t2.asn
AND t1.ean = t2.ean
AND t1.belegnr =  t2.belegnr
AND t1.quantity = t2.quantity
WHERE t2.asn = 700000845
AND t2.`belegnr` in(30059314,30059320)
AND t1.id IS NULL
```

Below is the my expected result

```
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+---------------------- 
| asn        |       ean |    oldean|       belegnr |quantity|Oldqty|
+------+--------------+----------------+-----+----------------------|
|  700000845 | 4046228201122| 4046228201122 |30059314 |2  |   5     |
|  700000845 | 4046228138875| 4046228138888 |30059320 |25  |  25    |
+------+--------------+----------------+--+--+--------+-------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there an `id` field in these tables that links the entries? Otherwise the result you want is not achievable (there is no way to prevent it trying to match both rows from both tables which have `belegnr = 30059314`).

Comment: @Nick, asn number is common in both tables and id is also there in both tables

Comment: if the id is the same in both tables JOIN on that.

Comment: @danblack, no id is not same. because that is temporary table and processing the data from temp table will be flushed

Comment: your question isn't possible to answer then as like @Nick said, no solid criteria for a join.. Why have you got a temporary table that you're trying to compare to an 'old version' maybe it can be resolved at that.

Comment: Because ,first user needs to accept if there is any change. I can not directly update old records with new records. After user approval only I can update.Thats why I am using temporary table

Comment: Then you need to copy the `id` value from the old table to the temporary table and `JOIN` on that.

Comment: I think copying id is not possible, because I don't know which id is associated with which records. and the data from temporay table is not same like original values

Answer (score 0):

Once you JOIN you've eliminated the t1 rows that you want to refer to as "old".

Assuming the asn is constant:

```
SELECT
t2.asn,t2.ean,t1.ean as oldean,t2.belegnr,t1.belegnr as oldbelegnr, t2.`quantity`,t1.`quantity` as Oldqty
FROM temp_table  t2
JOIN details  t1 ON t1.asn = t2.asn
WHERE
t1.ean <> t2.ean
OR t1.belegnr <>  t2.belegnr
OR t1.quantity <> t2.quantity
```

Comment: what exactly is the common criteria for the rows? your query has `t2.id` but no other mention of `id`.

Comment: asn value is common in both tables

Comment: please see this screen shot. This is exactly I am getting from your query. Even  I have added DISTINCT keyword. http://prntscr.com/mh7ekp

Comment: regarding t2.id, just I used that to display

Comment: with multiple asns in both tables duplicates can be expected. So really the asn isn't the only JOIN criteria, but you're expecting differences in the other fields. Are you expecting at most 1 difference per row? What if there's two?

Comment: yes, in belegnr, ean and quantity fields values may be change and I need any value changes out of the 3 fields I need to display to user

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

Note that if the data set was as follows, the problem would be no less difficult to understand...

Temporay table

```
+-----+-----+-----------+-------+
| asn | ean  |   belegnr |quantity|
+-----+-----+------------+-----+
|  845 | 1122|      14 |     2  |
|  845 | 8879|      14 |     3  |
|  845 | 8875|      20 |    25 |
+-----+------+-----------+-------+
```